# .Sum() return type for no rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have two tables "Question" and "Answer". Their association is as follows:

```
    public class Answer
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid? QuestionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Question? Question { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(1024)] public string Question { get; set; }

        public int? MaxMarks { get; set; }
    }
```

Scoring system is applicable on some questions only that's why `MaxMarks` is nullable

```
        TotalScore = s.Answers
                        .Where(a => a.Question.MaxMarks.HasValue)
                        .Sum(a => a.Question.MaxMarks)
```

I am getting an error on this line

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()

I tried to explicitly type casting it to int , but it didn't work.
Does anyone know what exactly is happening here?

Also what exactly will the `.Sum()` function return when no rows are passed to it: (`null` or `0`)

Comment: "Also What exactly will the .Sum() function returns when no rows are passed to it" - you can very easily find that out. What the reason for your problem is: Did you check if the result will be > int.MaxValue?

Comment: Well there won't be any case where my result would exceed the max int value, also all the values in the ```MaxMarks``` column are null for the time being

Comment: Did you have `long` before and changed the type to `int` and did you use the `long` version to create the table in the db? What column type is it?

Comment: Please check your db. Is `MaxMarks ` is int or bigint on table `Question`?

Comment: Thank you so much @HeinzSiahaan , @Fildor , Yes I was using ```bigint``` earlier and forgot to update the database.

Comment: A mistake you won't make twice ;)